# Is this plant a Creeping Bellflower?

Tags: identification, flowers

I got some more plants from a friend and before I plant them I want to make sure they are not creeping bellflowers. They are a little different, but I'm not completely sure. I'm hoping they are Harebell or something similar.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQfS8.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Harebell is a non specific term applied to various, usually taller varieties of Campanula - the plant/s you're showing appear to be Campanula persicifolia. If by 'creeping bellflower' you mean varieties of Campanula such as C. carpatica or C. porscharskyana, the plants you show, whilst related, are not creeping ground cover varieties, but taller herbaceous perennials. C. persicifolia does seed itself, but not prolifically and they're easy to remove or move elsewhere. Information and image below

http://www.lightscapes.info/onewithnature/natures-garden/wildflowers/campanulaceae/peach-leaved-bellflower-campanula-persicifolia/